# Rails dynamic grouped_collection_select automatically change

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a form with 1 collection_select and 2 grouped_collection_select.

All 3 start out with their include_blank.  As I choose the first collection select, the first grouped_collection_select, next select, will change automatically.  The issue is the 2nd grouped_collection_select, next select (3d select), option will not change along with it.  It will change only once I reselect the 1st grouped_collection_select.

Form:

```
<%= form_for @shop_product do |f| %>
    <%= f.collection_select :category_id, @categories, :id, :title, include_blank: "Select Category" %>
    <%= f.grouped_collection_select :style_id, @categories.order(:title), :styles, :title, :id, :title, include_blank: "Select Style", prompt: "Selet Style 2"  %>
    <%= f.grouped_collection_select :item_id, @styles.order(:title), :items, :title, :id, :title, include_blank: "Select Item"  %>
    ...
```

Javscript file:

```
jQuery(function() {
  var styles;
  styles = $('#shop_product_style_id').html();
  console.log(styles);
  return $('#shop_product_category_id').change(function() {
    var category, escaped_category, options;
    category = $('#shop_product_category_id :selected').text();
    escaped_category = category.replace(/([ #;&,.+*~\':"!^$[\]()=>|\/@])/g, '\\$1');
    options = $(styles).filter("optgroup[label=" + category + "]").html();
    console.log(options);
    if (options) {
      $('#shop_product_style_id').html(options);
      return $('#shop_product_style_id').parent().show();
    } else {
      return $('#shop_product_style_id').empty();
    }
  });
});

jQuery(function() {
  var items;
  items = $('#shop_product_item_id').html();
  console.log(items);
  return $('#shop_product_style_id').change(function() {
    var style, escaped_style, options;
    style = $('#shop_product_style_id :selected').text();
    escaped_style = style.replace(/([ #;&,.+*~\':"!^$[\]()=>|\/@])/g, '\\$1');
    options = $(items).filter("optgroup[label=" + style + "]").html();
    console.log(options);
    if (options) {
      $('#shop_product_item_id').html(options);
      return $('#shop_product_item_id').parent().show();
    } else {
      return $('#shop_product_item_id').empty();
    }
  });
});
```

Models:

```
**shop_product.rb**

  belongs_to :category
  belongs_to :style
  belongs_to :item

**category.rb**

  has_many :shop_products
  has_many :styles

**style.rb**

  has_many :shop_products
  belongs_to :category
  has_many :items

**item.rb**

  has_many :shop_products
  belongs_to :style
```

Is the issue for example:

1. I choose a category
2. Styles appear, lets say "hoodies" is in the select field
3. Item doesn't change.

In order to change Item, I need to select the :style_id field, select something other than "hoodies", reselect "hoodies", then will Items appear that have the `Item.style_id == "hoodies"`

I would like for the 3rd select for `item_id` to change at the same time `style_id` changes when the @category is chosen.  Also to have them all reset if the @categories collection_select is put back to "Select Category".

How can I have it so everything is uniform together? How can the :item_id grouped_collection_select field change when style_id does so I don't need to reselect to change it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `trigger` function

```
  ...
  else {
    return $('#shop_product_style_id').empty();
  }
  $('#shop_product_style_id').trigger('change')
});
```

this will call `$('#shop_product_style_id').change(function...`